# Android: How to run a part an activity in the background?

Tags: android

I have an activity which I want to be able to run in the foreground, however there is one line of code in this activity which I would like to run when the activity goes into the background. How can I do this?

Comment: Call it from within onPause().

Comment: have you tried with a service? or with a thread (asynctask and such)? Any code showing what have you tried would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods to handle scenarios when the application goes to background and comes back to foreground, respectively. However, keep in mind that `onPause()` will get called when the activity is destroyed. See the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) for more details.